# How to get some particular values of attribute in XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an xml which contains below code

```
<row index="2" i1="input.value&gt;5" i2="4" o1="5" />
```

attribute `i1` is an expression: `input.value>5`

I have a requirement if user enters anything greater than 5 then it should match the xml and return true.

```
XElement oDataRowNode = _oDecisionTableDOM.XPathSelectElement(xPath);
```

above code giving me exact matches. Can anyone help me out on figuring out this expression checking in asp.net c#

Comment: The jxml was html encoded so you need to use  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Comment: are you asking for an xpath or any other solution would be okay? what have you tried?

Comment: @jdweng Yes i can give Decoding but how can i compare expressions , i1=6 if i give it should match with Xelement..

Comment: @derloopkat  anything is fine. I need that condition to be matched.  bool exists = _oDecisionTableDOM.Elements("data")
                  .Elements("row")
                  .Where(x => x.Value.Contains("input.value"))
                  .Any();
I tried with Linq.. still not getting exact logic to figure this out.